# EF Core MySql autoincrement field

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-migrations, auto-increment, ef-core-2.0

I'm developing Asp.Core application with Entity Framework Core.

I need autoincrement proerty, starting with 1000000.

I was trying

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bill>().Property(p => p.Number).HasComputedColumnSql("Id + 1000000");
```

but get en error

```
Generated column 'Number' cannot refer to auto-increment column.
```

How can i do non primary key autoincrement property with EF Core and MySql?

Comment: You can set the starting value for auto increment when you create the table or with an ALTER TABLE.  You will want to scan https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html for details

Comment: Try [Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences).

Comment: When i try to add second autoincrement field, i get an error: "there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"